# Como puedo arreglar la vista de mi footer

Tags: html, css

Les explico por encima yo a todo los textos les di un margen de 20px, y mi footer quedaba flotando en el aire y abajo de el salía un espacio en blanco intenté agrandando su tamaño y el espacio blanco se agrandaba mas. si me podrían ayudar se los agradecería.

aca les dejo una foto de como se ve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ootdi.png

**Código HTML**

```
<footer>
       <div class="footer">
           <div class="copyright-notice">
               <h3>GRUPO SCOUT 1279 PAPA FRANCISCO</h3>
               <a type="button" href="" target="_blank" class="btn-floating footer waves-effect waves-light">
                   <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
               </a>
               <a type="button" href="" class="btn-floating footer  waves-effect waves-light" target="_blank">
                   <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
               </a>
               <p>&copy; Copyright </p>
           </div>
       </div>
   </footer>
```

**Código CSS**

```
.footer {
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 86px;
}

.copyright-notice {
    color: #30343a;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: Agrega todo el HTML y CSS aquí, para algunos es difícil acceder a enlaces,  aquí puedes agregar el código necesario para comprender tu problema, edita tu pregunta las veces que sean necesarias.

Comment: full completo? @AntonioGalacia

Comment: De preferencia, con esto das a conocer la estructura de tu pagina, así como la posibilidad de replicar tu código para obtener una buena respuesta.

Comment: Me pregunto como @Maidagan sabia el codigo html que hacia falta...

Comment: Ha añadido un enlace a una página donde tenía el código que he añadido. Por comodidad para todos, he editado la pregunta y he añadido ahí el código, que es lo que debería de haber hecho Tobias desde un inicio

Comment: @Maidagan pero entonces se lo hiciste y no lo enseñaste o no aprendio a hacerlo... de seguro que si lo hace de nuevo volverias a ayudarlo de esta manera?

Comment: La verdad es que tienes razón, debería de haberle puesto un comentario y que el lo hiciese, para que la próxima vez lo haga el solo. Pero he estaba un poco saturado y he decidido hacerlo yo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[La norma](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp) de HTML5 indica que en el documento o por cada section puede haber un footer.

Luego tienes que sacar el footer de la sección de contacto, Fíjate en la imagen. El footer con el número 1 está dentro de la  y el footer 2 está fuera. Tienes que dejarlo como la última imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿cuantos footer debe tener un html?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 No hay límites para ocupar la etiqueta footer. En este caso tiene un solo, yo solo modifiqué el html para que hubieran 2, uno dentro de una "section" y otro fuera. Así el OP viera que si lo deja fuera su problema se soluciona

Comment: una consulta como sacaste el codigo completo sin que halla pasado la web?

Comment: listo muchas gracias :)

Comment: @TobiasCampomenosi Porque soy un mago!!!! :PP (busqué group scout 1279 en google)

Comment: jajaj ta bien gracias por la ayuda capo @Yussef